# Discord bot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bots, chatbot

I have created a chatbot in python and used following code to run it **"client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))"**
What is the alternative in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

In discord.js, we use `.login` to run the bot.

```
client.login("<Put your token here");
```